# Переход на каталог ниже или выше

Tags: c#

Нужно создать дерево каталогов. Допустим понятно как просмотреть все файлы в каталоге и все папки, а как после просмотра всего этого перейти  на каталог выше или ниже ?

```
 string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
 string[] directory = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     label2.Text = label2.Text + files[i].ToString() + "\r\n";
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
 {
     label3.Text = label3.Text + directory[j].ToString() + "\r\n";                
 }
```

Не уверен, что верно всё это делаю, но как знаю.
И еще вопрос: как определить количество файлов или папок в директории, чтобы прописать его в условии ?

Comment: Добавил свой говнокод.

Comment: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6767995#p6767995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перейти ниже можно получив список папок в текущей директории, что у вас и сделано (`Directory.GetDirectories()`).

Перейти выше можно, используя свойство [`DirectoryInfo.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Console.WriteLine(info.Parent?.Name ?? "this is a root directory");
```

Однако при построении дерева каталогов переход на каталог выше вам ни к чему. Достаточно обхода вниз. Пример обхода с рекурсией:

```
public void DirSearch(string path) 
{
    try 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) 
       {
           foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d)) 
           {
               Console.WriteLine(f);
           }
           DirSearch(d);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

...

string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
DirSearch(path);
```